# gridview paging

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with about 300-400 rows that I use for reporting; it needs paging and requires sorting. My choice is between these two options: a) load the 300-400 in one query and let the gridview do the paging and sorting; b) handle the paging/sorting at the data source level. I know that b) is going to be better/faster/more efficient... In my context, I'm looking to get something done relatively fast; if I choose a), will the page seem incredibly/painfully slow?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use an ajax control that control the page size client side, try looking in www.codeproject.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the builtin functions of the GridView and load the whole data at one go. It wouldn't be worth the effort to implement paging in database(f.e. with RowNumber) when your number of records is such small, especially because you mentioned that you are looking for a fast solution. When you enable paging in GridView the performance will suffice.

Comment: @downvoters: I wonder that nobody comments the downvotes. If you would have to pay for the extra time(0,5-3 days) for a db-paging solution which isn't needed at all in this case, you would argue completely different.

Comment: Eventually the grid will have paging; but I don't know when. It actually looks like it might be pretty soon because another grid is going to need paging and when I'll do that, I might as well spend a little more time and page this particular grid as well. For those who downvote, keep in mind that end users want the application finished, not perfect. Just get it done man!

Answer (score 1):

read Scott Guthrie's [excellent article about paging](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/01/434314.aspx).

> How to implement a data-result search page built with ASP.NET 2.0 and Atlas that can present hundreds of thousands of row results using the ASP.NET 2.0 GridView control.  The results are formatted using a “paging” based UI model – where 15 results per page are displayed, and the user can skip from page to page to see their data.  For kicks I also added support for editing and deleting each individual row.

Answer (score 0):

Although 300-400 rows isn't a particularly large set of data, I would certainly vote for option B since it will definitely be more scalable. Once you start getting massive sets of data, loading all of it with one query and having the GridView handle the paging will end up being incredibly slow. The better option is to, like you said, only query the data you need for each page.

However, if you aren't going to have data sets larger than 300-400 records, you probably don't need to be too concerned about load times, but again, the key is in scalability.

Comment: thanks. In my this particular case, the dataset will never exceed 300-500 rows because it's used in the context of reporting some sort of daily activity. Do you mean scalability in terms of how many simultaneous users a server can handle?

Comment: @frenchie: I'm talking about paging thousands or hundreds of thousands of records, but since you won't be exceeding 300-500 records, you can get away with paging the data at the view level.