# Datagridview information load very slow with multiple records

Tags: asp.net

I have a DataGridView where I show some information on the Web, everything works fine when I have few records but the problem is when the DataGridView tries to load more than 300 records or so, because the page takes a long time loading information.

The question is there a way to optimize such queries with a Datagridview?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776807/gridview-paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making sure you use the good practices:

- eliminate viewstate if possible (that could be a lot of hidden data)
- use DataGridView paging to keep request times down by showing data in pages of 10, 20, 30, ...
- if paging is not nessesary, use a DataList or Repeater to reduce the overhead of the object
- deploy solution from release build without any debugging or tracing directives

If that does not help, use profiler such as ANTS or dotTrace to investigate DataGridView behavior.

These tools will show you exactly where the bottlenecks are.